# Playing video in browser glitches

Tags: video, browser, playback

Is there any way to fix this problem when I play videos in a browser. Doesn't matter if its Chrome or Mozilla. Same goes when playing gifs, tho they stabilized after a few loops. Video playbacks seem to be fine with VLC, even when network streaming. Watching Twitch streams seems fine.

My specs are:

- i7 920
- Ati Radeon 4870 1GB
- Main disk is SSD
- Windows 10 64 bit

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

1. In your address bar type `about:plugins`
2. On top right inside the windows click `+Details` to reveal more info on all plugins
3. Under name look for Shockwave Flash once you've found that look at its location it should look something like this:

   ```
   C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrom­e\Application\2X.X.XXXX.XX\PepperFlash\p­epflashplayer.dll
   ```
4. Once you found the one with Pepper Flash in it Disable it.
5. Exit out of all Chrome windows to insure that the browser restarts Sucessfully

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I managed to disable hardware acceleration on both browsers and now everything is rendering fine. I'll keep this as an answer for future possible solutions :)